# Primefaces Inplace editor - save never gets fired

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a simple form combining primefaces and JSF. I'm using one of primefaces's components called inplace in editor mode, but for some reason, the "save" event never calls the backing bean, even though the "cancel" does.
Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Form

```
<h:form 
    id="base-form">
    <p:inplace 
        id="base-editor"
        editor="true">
        <p:inputText value="#{bean.user.name}" />
        <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{bean.save()}" />
        <p:ajax event="cancel" listener="#{bean.cancel()}" />
    </p:inplace>
</h:form>
```

BackingBean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
public class UserBean(){
    private User user = new User();

    public void save() {
        System.out.println("Save called");
    }

    public void cancel() {
        user = new User();
        System.out.println("Cancel called");
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {this.user = user}
    public User getUser(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you just need EL like `value="#{bean.user.name}"`.

And you also need a scope on the bean. Try `@ViewScoped`. And `implements Serializable` on it.

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake, but I have that on my actual code. The problem is with the save event that never gets fired though

Comment: No problem, did you try with scope?

Comment: I tried view and request scoped. None of them worked

Comment: javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped and not the other one?

Comment: And I expect getUser() returns something?

Comment: Yeah It does. Sorry for these mistakes Im on my phone xD. By the way I used the right ViewScoped and unfurtunately It Didnt work

Comment: Well there is something you're not showing as it works for me. Of course you need get/setName on User

Comment: I'll search more on this. I'm  stuck here for hours. Thank you anyways

Comment: Do other PF components work? What server are you on? Is above code all there is? As said, it works for me in Glassfish 4, PF 5.3

Comment: Im using TomCat 7 JSF 2.2 and PF 5

Comment: Solved the problem after re-installing TomCat and updating PrimeFaces to version 5.3. Thank you for pointing out your version :)